# Change it so that when you press the "Twitter" button on the bottom of the page it goes to the site's account instead of Stack Overflow's

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, twitter

When you go to the bottom of the page of any Stack Exchange site, you find a small button called "Twitter" on the right side.

The problem is, when you click on it, instead of it redirecting you to the site's Twitter account, it goes to Stack Overflow's Twitter account.

Should the "Twitter" button redirect you to the site's Twitter account? (Except for sites that don't have any Twitter account.)

Comment: Actually most sites don't and won't have Twitter accounts. And as a su mod, the operation of the tweetbot is a mystery to me

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Well, you are a bit right check the [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) page and there are about 60 sites with no Twitter account. To me, the Tweetbot is to post new, hot, or any other posts on their Twitter account for users and non-users to see. The only different Twitter account is Stack Overflow.

Comment: I need some official sources to tell me if this is getting added. Anybody help?

Comment: Most of the per-site Twitter accounts have also been retired now as of Twitter's API change. See Catija's answer here: [Are the various site Tweetbots affected by the upcoming Twitter API changes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386451/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast That doesn't mean that the site's old Twitter accounts from the time they were active have all been deleted, though.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: That's true, but... I don't really see how it's relevant. We're not going to bother linking to Twitter accounts that are no longer active, even if they haven't been deleted. (For reference, we also removed the Twitter links from the https://stackexchange.com/sites list.)